# Kivymd MDNavigation Drawer disable swipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

i'm using **kivy** to build an app, and i implemented the **MD Navigation Drawer** feature to the app and i have problem disabling the swipe option in my Navigation Drawer, i tried `enable_swiping = False`, but doesn't work at all and the drawer still moving by mouse dragging, so the main goal is to open & close the navigation drawer by a button click, and prevent the user to do same thing by sliding the drawer.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution but better than default anyway :)

Try set swipe_edge_width and elevation to 0 in your KV-code. It will however, still be possible to drag out the navigator at the very edge of the screen..

```
NavigationLayout:

    ScreenManager:

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        swipe_edge_width: 0
        elevation: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using python code like:

```
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer

drawer = MDNavigationDrawer()
drawer.swipe_distance = drawer.width
```

In this way, there will be no horizontal swiping.